# Efficiently transform float and double values into bytes that preserve the comparison relationship between values

Tags: algorithm

I need a method by which to efficiently translate any **float** or **double** value to an **array of bytes** so that it preserves the comparison relationship to any other value.

Example: **V1** and **V2** are turned into arrays **A1** and **A2**. If **A1**[0]<**A2**[0], then **V1** must be smaller than **V2**. Same for larger. If **A1**[0]==**A2**[0] and **A1**[1]>**A2**[1] then **V1** must be larger than **V2**. And so on. If all the bytes are the same, then the values **V1** and **V2** must be equal.

For a four byte integer **I**, an array that would satisfy the above condition would be [**U**>>24, (**U**>>16)&255, (**U**>>8)&255, **U**&255], where U is the uint positive value **V**-int.MinValue.

Since doubles are stored as 8 bytes, I expect something close to 8 bytes.

Do you think such a thing can be achieved? Thanks!

C# solution is preferred.

Comment: In which language? The techniques available in C# may differ from those available in JavaScript.

Comment: I need a general thing. C# preferred.

Comment: (I wanted to remove the JS tag, but I felt that wasn't for me to do.)

Comment: Please don't spam the tags. If you want an algorithm that is not specific to a language, use the `language-agnostic` tag. If you want C# code, use the `c#` tag. If you want JavaScript, use the `javascript` tag.

Comment: When you ask a computer related question and you get a syntax error... Geez!

Comment: Odd thing about your question is it does not address [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: In thinking about this it seems that you will eventually recreate the comparison part of the float and double API, so I don't see the benefit of what you seek unless it is for learning. The biggest problem I think you will encounter is that your datatype is an `int` but it really needs to be an `algebraic data type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard representation for doubles and floats that is used by most languages, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), is already very close to supporting this requirement.

In C#, you can use [BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.doubletoint64bits?view=netcore-3.1) or [SingleToInt32Bits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.singletoint32bits?view=netcore-3.1) to get the underlying bits of a double or float directly as an integer.

In order to make comparisons work out right, you only have to fix up the way negative numbers are handled:

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits( theDouble );
if (bits < 0L) {
    bits ^= Int64.MaxValue;
}
```

The resulting `long`s will then have the same numeric order as the corresponding `double`s.  This works for all values except `Nan`, which isn't really comparable to anything else.  The infinities, +0.0 and -0.0 work fine.

If you want +0.0 and -0.0 to have the same value, you can do this:

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits( theDouble );
if (bits < 0L) {
    bits = (bits^Int64.MaxValue)+1L;
}
```

Note that if you want to make your byte array, you'll probably want to convert to an unsigned integer.  You need to flip the sign bit if you want to preserve the ordering, or just do it like this:

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits( theDouble );
ulong arraybits;
if (bits >= 0L) {
    arraybits = (1UL<<63) + (ulong)bits;
} else {
    arraybits = (ulong)~bits;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, Matt! I'll test it and mark it as an answer soon.

Comment: It works just as advertised, I am marking it as the correct answer. One small note: SingleToInt32Bits does not work for .NET Framework, therefore it's not available for a .NET Standard 2.0 library either.